# How to initiate a phone call in a web app on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, iphone-standalone-web-app

I want to implement a JavaScript API to initiate phone calls programmatically and without the need for a native Objective-C implementation.

What I tried so far was something like `location.href='tel:12345';`. The result was an error with the message "The URL can’t be shown".

My second attempt was to create a hidden link (like `<a href="tel:12345">call</a>`) and click it programmatically. This didn't work either, although the link worked when not hidden and clicked manually by the user.

Is it possible to achieve this with JavaScript only or do I need to delegate to the Objective-C part of the application to initiate the call from there?

Comment: are you adding this to the homescreen?

Comment: It's a native app with a UIWebView in which the web app resides. So similar to phonegap, but too different, to just use phonegap.

Comment: the `UIWebView` is different from Safari, you will have to figure out how to handle the url differently.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `tel:12345` have you tried `tel://12345` ?

Comment: But in Mobile Safari this makes all the difference. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="tel:1-800-xxx-xxxx">call</a>
```

Is your url is correct?

Comment: Do you mean the "-"? I don't believe that they are necessary. For example here in germany phone number fragments are separated just by whitespace or not separated at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.open()` for this:

```js
window.open( 'tel:800-888-1234', '_top' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to write the code to do so natively and create a JavaScript function to be called from within the WebView.